# Automatically copy values every day into new tab - Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm currently building a script that takes information that is updated daily and saves the values in a new tab for my records (no formulas as it would update the records).

This is my current code which I found online, but I can't for the life of me copy over just the values without the formulas.

Any ideas? I'm sure I'm just overlooking something.

```html
function createDeleteTabs() {
  
  /* DASHBOARD---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Edit this section to change the dates tabs are created for and the range of data that will be cleared each time! */
  
  var numberOfDaysForwardForNextTab = 0
  var numberOfDaysBackwardForDeleteTab = 0
  var rangeToClear = 'F5:CS'
  
  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();   // get the spreadsheet object
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[0]); // set the first sheet as active

  // Sets date for add tab & date for delete tab
  var MILLIS_PER_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
  var today = new Date();
  var addWeek = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(today.getTime() + (numberOfDaysForwardForNextTab * MILLIS_PER_DAY)), "GMT+1", "dd-MM-yy");
  var deleteWeek = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(today.getTime() - (numberOfDaysBackwardForDeleteTab * MILLIS_PER_DAY)), "GMT+1", "dd-MM-yy"); 
  
  // Adds tab
  ss.duplicateActiveSheet();
  ss.renameActiveSheet(addWeek); //Renames sheet to date from above
  ss.moveActiveSheet(1); //Moves sheet to the first position


}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell exactly what's going on, but I think you just need to grab all the values of a sheet (which I think I've identified as position 1?) and then just setValues. See below.

```
  // Adds tab
  ss.duplicateActiveSheet();
  ss.renameActiveSheet(addWeek); //Renames sheet to date from above
  ss.moveActiveSheet(1); //Moves sheet to the first position

  //new code
  var mySheet = ss.getSheetByName(addWeek);
  var theValues = mySheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  mySheet.getDataRange().setValues(theValues);
```